# Design Approaches to Storing Recently Used Items in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have a design problem with multiple solutions, I wanted to see if anyone could give insights on the quantitative trade offs to which approach is better.

**Problem:** I have a list of items in MongoDB, somewhere between 10 to 100,000 (reasonably). I would like to be able to present my top 100 recently used items in order from most recently used, to least recently used.

**Solution 1:** I add a timestamp to each of the MongoDB items. When I used the item, I update the timestamp for that item. To generate my top 100 recently used items, I query MongoDB, sort the items by last used timestamp, and then present the top 100 sorted items. My thoughts are, this solution adds the least amount of change to the current implementation, but could be slow if it's querying and sorting for example 100,000 items (especially if multiple users are performing this query).

**Solution 2:** I create a new MongoDB collection storing just the top 100 items in an array. Every time I used an item, I add an element to the array, and if the array is greater than 100 items, I pop the last item. My thoughts are, this solution seems to be faster since the query just returns everything from the recent collection.

In terms of performance (for the user), which approach is better? Or is there an alternate even better approach?